# How to send a salesforce sales cloud quick send message on behalf of someone else

Tags: salesforce-lightning

We have recently implemented Distributed Marketing in our organization.  We have 5 quick send messages for daily use by the reps.  We have a monthly newsletter that the reps send via Bulk Send.
Ideally we would have an admin. send out the emails - and the from address would populate with the area sales manager's name (not the contacts rep).
Does anyone know how to set this up in sales cloud?

Thank you, Marie

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a Distributed Marketing Sender Profile? This defines a %%sendFromName%% and %%sendFromEmail%% that can be used in AmpScript to assign values based on values you pass to it. For example, if your Lead/Person Account/Contact has a field that contains a reference to a Sales Rep, you could include that field as part of your Synchronized Data Extensions and then include that value on the Subscriber Profile as an attribute. You could then reference it using AmpScript and populate the send values.

Alternatively, you can use the Record Owner as the send from name and send from email (assuming you have appropriate ownership attribution in place). This is a setting in the Distributed Marketing Administration page.